# def user=User.findByUserIdAndPassword(params.userId,params.password) is null ?? IN GRAILS

Tags: grails, spring-security

`def user=User.findByUserIdAndPassword(params.userId,params.password)` is null even after successful signup ... I am using Spring Security.

My User domain class is

```
class User {

   transient springSecurityService

   Integer id 
   String userId
   String password
   byte[] photo
   String fullName
   String bio
   String email
   String address
   String username

   boolean enabled
   boolean accountExpired
   boolean accountLocked
   boolean passwordExpired

   static hasMany = [places: Place, badges: Badge, checkIns:CheckIn, friend:User]

   static belongsTo = Place

   String toString(){
      "$userId"
   }

   static constraints = {
      fullName(nullable: true,maxSize:20,matches:"[a-zA-Z\40-\176]+")
      bio(nullable: true, maxSize: 100,matches:"[a-zA-Z\40-\176]+")
      email(email: true, blank: false)
      photo(nullable: true,maxSize:1000000)
      address( nullable:true,maxSize:40,matches:"[a-zA-Z0-9\40-\176]+")
      userId(size:5..10,unique:true,nullable:false,matches:"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")
      password(size:5..10,password:true,nullable:false)
      username blank: false, unique: true
   }

   static mapping = {
      password column: '`password`'
   }

   Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
      UserAuthority.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.authority } as Set
   }

   def beforeInsert() {
      encodePassword()
   }

   def beforeUpdate() {
      if (isDirty('password')) {
         encodePassword()
      }
   }

   protected void encodePassword() {
      password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
   }
}
```

if I implement

```
System.out.println(" userid------------------->" + params.userId);
System.out.println(" password------------------->" + params.password);
System.out.println(" username------------------->" + params.username);
```

I am able to see the userId and password of the user logged in ...but why is

`def user=User.findByUserIdAndPassword(params.userId,params.password)` NULL??

Answer (score 1):

The password is stored hashed in the database. Therefore params.password does not match the value stored in the database.

Besides - what are you trying to achieve? You can access a user manually by accessing the service:

springSecurityService.currentUser

And for login purposes I would suggest using the spring-security-ui plugin.

Hope that helps :)